# How do I pass a statement as an argument?

Tags: ruby

Specifically in ruby, I'm wondering if I am able to do something.

Let's say I have a while loop that does something until a condition is no longer met.
I will be needing this same while loop for multiple purposes but the condition changes every time. Thus I want change it to a function for re-usability purposes.

Is it possible for me to pass (what condition I'm checking for) as an argument?

Something like:

```
def wait(condition)
  while condition
    do something
  end
end
```

To clarify, I want to pass the condition (or statement) itself, not the evaluation of the statement at the time of running the function.
Also I'm pretty sure I'm giving these the wrong names (statement/condition/evaluation) so please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that with blocks:

```
def wait(&condition)
    while condition.call()
        # do something
    end
end

...

wait {true} # never returns
```

See http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/ for some useful information.

Comment: However it gives me an error when I run wait({true}) :
irb(main):063:0> wait({true})
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):63: odd number list for Hash
wait({true})
           ^
        from (irb):63
        from :0
irb(main):064:0>

Comment: ...Sorry new here. How do I enter linefeed in the comments?

Comment: @kennyg: You can't have multiline comments, unfortunately. :( You can format code by putting it between backticks (`\``) though. (And as for your error - I have no idea. It works for me on Interactive Ruby. Did you make sure to add the `&` before `condition` in `wait`?)

Comment: Yes the & is there. I am also using interactive ruby.

Comment: Block args are treated specially, you have to call `wait` without the parentheses: `wait {true}` or put the block after: `wait() {true}`. You could pass the condition as a lambda if you want it to be treated like a regular argument.

Comment: @kennyg: My bad, it should be `wait {true}`.

Comment: @BenoitGarret: Oops, missed your comment. You're right. Figured it out, though :)

Comment: Works perfectly minitech, thanks! I would upvote you but apparently I don't have enough reputation :-\

Answer (score 2):

```
def print_while(value, &condition)
  while condition.call
    print value
  end
end
```

or:

```
def wait(value)
  while yield
    print value
  end
end
```

To call:

```
wait(2) { true }
```

Comment: `def wait(value) print value while yield end` should do the same and looks cleaner IMO.